# In PostgreSQL, how do you find all the tables that are using a specific enum type?

Tags: postgresql

Error : ERROR:  cannot drop type `some enum type` because other objects depend on it

How do I know which objects depend on it?

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT table_name, column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE data_type = 'USER-DEFINED' AND udt_name = 'my enum type name'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?). But this one works for me:

`SELECT c.table_name, c.column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables t ON t.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE c.data_type = 'USER-DEFINED' AND udt_name = 'manufacturer_model_name';`